# Merge two columns fron one table in to a new view with sql

Tags: sql

I have a table that has two columns, Loser and Winner. Can I create a new view with one column: "Player" that has all the losers and winners but only unique values?

Comment: Can you provide some sample schema and what have you tried ?

Comment: Please tag your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create view x as 
select loser as player from table
union
select winner from table;
```

Comment: I didnt need to ask any questions since the answer was copy paste material ;-). Absolutely perfect.